# Why does this macro take 40 seconds to run?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried so many things, and am still finding that this macro takes 40 seconds to run. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I could make this more efficient?

```
Public CalcState As Long
Public EventState As Boolean
Public PageBreakState As Boolean

Sub OptimizeCode_Begin()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

CalcState = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub

Sub OptimizeCode_End()

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState
Application.Calculation = CalcState
Application.EnableEvents = EventState
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub Input_V2()
Call OptimizeCode_Begin
    Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("a6:x6").Insert: Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("a6:x6").Value2 = Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("a3:x3").Value2
With Sheets("R_Database Sheet").Range("a6:x6")
    .ClearFormats
    .RowHeight = 15
End With

Call OptimizeCode_End
End Sub
```

Comment: If that takes 40 seconds to run there is stuff going on that you have not mentioned. E.g. do you have any other code in the file?

Comment: Which operation takes the longest?

Answer (score 0):

When inserting a Range, Excel has to check whether other formulas in the open workbooks need adjusting to compensate for the insertion. If you have a large number of formulas or some complex formulas this operation can be slow.